# Como selecionar uma string no resx (internacionalização) sem utilizar o método estático

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho arquivos .resx onde guardo strings em inglês e português, no meu banco de dados eu tenho a seguinte tabela:
[image: Banco de dados 1]

E quero mudar a descrição dos planos igual o primeiro registro dessa tabela:
[image: Banco de dados 2]

Com isso poderei pegar essa string "plano_1" direto do meu resource assim conseguindo transforma-lo em inglês e português.

Mas como o resource só deixa eu pegar os métodos estáticos com as strings dentro, não consigo resolver esse problema.

Gostaria de ao invés de fazer isso : `string plano1 = Messages.plano_1;` utilizar a string que eu vou puxar do banco de dados algo do tipo `string plano1 = Messages("plano_1")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar o [`ResourceManager.GetString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d17ax2xk.aspx) pra isso

```
var resManager = Messages.ResourceManager;
string plano1 = resManager.GetString("plano_1");
```